# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. when installing Tensorflow in Colab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm getting this error when pip installing tflite-model-maker in Colab notebook. Does anyone know what's causing this? It was working fine yesterday but it's now giving me this error today. The error appears in the end, and the download slows down to almost a stop; from 5 minutes before to over 30 minutes now.

This is the code I'm running:

```
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker
!pip install -q tflite-support
```

Full error:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/3d/cfd8ad26e76a6e15f5b01ae2eb680470d949f50bdb65146edaafb414fdf4/python-slugify-0.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=31a972486b9d39194bea9c67f1311a37ac9f58f05ac21604b189293426050b74 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-slugify/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/a7/ed24b46ae9ae16d67efc6ad14f86bfcb3a02f7df609da055729528ed45c6/python-slugify-0.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=fe4c2f52c2c881e3bfeb085f4eabeecea60672612b492d5ff18a2df7ae1508e7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-slugify/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/4f/423a44a5c00ef9e1a34ef0463a8da14d586bd6cdc60a4f5d39c85f7ae6f5/python-slugify-0.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=3ed633fe2d2683b2747ce1224ea91bab49f509c57886c3a9a5dcd33e0d7de171 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-slugify/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/aa/4d37e9751789507852b0b97c45563efaaa973ff2dbeffef98e12ef6f03fa/python-slugify-0.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=3169a3f22e8cbdb4891287b827a9c052f77c5cb92e6d9521415220a7696c2220 (from https://pypi.org/simple/python-slugify/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Maybe it's of value, but I duplicated this notebook today before using it and the error popped up after. I already deleted the duplicate notebooks, changed accounts, and tried it on a different notebook, but still no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I updated pip in the Colab to the latest version (from 21.1.3 to 22.2.2) and it fixed it somehow. I get this warning message whenever I run the cell but it still installs tf-model-maker and support successfully.

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```